# How to access Data from posts in FB pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, restfb

I have a requirement of getting data, to be specific, images from posts on those public pages in FB. I registered an app on Facebook and tried to access the page data it says:

> To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

Can I use some scraping library and do it on a daily basis? Please guide.

What procedure should I follow to get this thing done?

Comment: Perhaps it is necesary and mandatory in order to comply with facebook security standars, they just want to ensure you wont missuse the access to public information due to the current privacy standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get data from Pages you don´t own, you have to submit your App to Facebook. They need to approve Page Public Content Access first. You can only test it with Pages you manage, and you need to use a Page Token of those Pages for it.

There is no other way, scraping is not allowed on Facebook.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/?locale=de_DE#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: @lunchn what do you mean by "You can only test it with Pages you manage, and you need to use a Page Token of those Pages for it."

Comment: what part of that sentence is unclear? some specific words?

Comment: e.g. If I want to access data ( e.g. for sentiment analysis ) from another public page that I don't manage, can I build a prototype app using my own page because if I understand, I can't prototype using other public pages.

Comment: of course you can build a prototype using your own page(s), but access to other pages is permitted unless you go through review.